# iOS App crashed in compiler generated code on iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift

> 1. I got this error in fabric crashalytics.
> 2. It show as Compiler generated error.
> 3. I have tried many things to resolved it but that not works.
> 4. I need help. I'm new in development.

"I have tried many scenario to reproduce error  like reload data and rotate device but it works properly in my device iphone 6 but in client iphone XR it crashes."

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  WorkInProgress                 0x10471dc58 specialized 
WIPInsightNewVC.collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:) (<compiler- 
generated>)

1  WorkInProgress                 0x104713390 @objc 
   WIPInsightNewVC.collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:) (<compiler- 
   generated>)
2  UIKitCore                      0x1be82c200 - 
   [UICollectionViewFlowLayout 
   _getSizingInfosWithExistingSizingDictionary:] + 2976
3  (Missing)                      0x4a655d81be82d800 (Missing)
4  (Missing)                      0x0 (Missing)
5  (Missing)                      0x741c9081be820800 (Missing)
6  (Missing)                      0x791e1b01be821000 (Missing)
7  (Missing)                      0x7516ca81be7f1c00 (Missing)
8  (Missing)                      0x0 (Missing)
9  (Missing)                      0x1b2e2401bac27b00 (Missing)
10 (Missing)                      0x1674481c19ee0f0 (Missing)
11 (Missing)                      0x0 (Missing)
12 (Missing)                      0x0 (Missing)
13 (Missing)                      0x3311a201c1946c00 (Missing)
14 (Missing)                      0xa4c0701c1971c00 (Missing)
15 (Missing)                      0x414a1f81c1972800 (Missing)
16 (Missing)                      0x0 (Missing)
17 (Missing)                      0x0 (Missing)
18 (Missing)                      0x4b0edd81bae87800 (Missing)
19 (Missing)                      0x597e0b01bae87000 (Missing)
20 (Missing)                      0x0 (Missing)
21 (Missing)                      0x0 (Missing)
22 (Missing)                      0x0 (Missing)
23 libdyld.dylib                  0x1bad06f30 start + 4
```

> code in sizeForItemAt method and it might be it will help you to solve my problem.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    var width = view.frame.width - 40
    let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    var estimatedFrame = CGRect()
    var size = CGSize()

    size = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)

    if collectionView == progressCV {

        let obj = (appDel?.objActiveUserTaskProgress?.workProgressRecords?[indexPath.row])!
        estimatedFrame = NSAttributedString(attributedString: obj.pROGRESSTASKDESCRIPTION.htmlAttributedString()!).boundingRect(with: size, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)
        sizes = Int(estimatedFrame.height)
    }
    else {
        let obj = (appDel?.objActiveUserTaskProgress?.graphDetails?[indexPath.row])!
        estimatedFrame = NSAttributedString(attributedString: obj.pROGRESSTASKDESCRIPTION.htmlAttributedString()!).boundingRect(with: size, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)
        sizes = Int(estimatedFrame.height)
    }

    print(sizes)
    if sizes <= 20 {
        sizes = 25
    }
    sizes += 64

    if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad {
        width = progressCV.bounds.width / 2 - 15
        return CGSize(width: Int(width), height: sizes)
    }
    else {
        if iphoneX {
            if width > height {
                width = progressCV.bounds.width
            }
        }
        return CGSize(width: Int(width), height: sizes)
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain what you are you trying, just posting the error wont get you a solution

Comment: explain your question. see that https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @vishal :  I'm getting crash report in fabric for compiler generated error so Please help me to solve it. I have tried different thing to resolved it but that not works. Thanks

Comment: @JakirHossain Please help me to solve it. I'm new in swift and iOS developement. I get this error log in fabric crash analytics.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson Please help me

Comment: How can we help you without seeing the code that causes the crash?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Okay I'm now giving code here.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Please see my updated question. I have added one method.

Comment: @Jagveer Singh Please see my updated question. I have added one method.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 13, whenever you hide (or) unhide a view, giving constant value to a height constraint and all will have to be done in main thread only.

Ex:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.heightConstraint.constant = 150
   self.listView.isHidden = true
}
```